# Need help understanging Firebug's Net tab statistics

Tags: performance, firebug, httprequest

Even though my question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100167/reading-time-reported-in-the-firebug-net-tab), it's not a duplicate.

[image: Firebug NET Tab screenshot]

The images shows the stats from Firebug's NET tab, each request is taking a fraction of a second (all requests add up to 2.9 sec), yet the total time adds up to 6 seconds.

How do I figure out which request took the longest time, and **where did the extra 3 seconds came from**?

Comment: Is it possible you are not in the 'All' tab?

Answer (score 2):

Requests are not necessarily in parallel. *Most browsers* only pull 2 concurrent resources per host. So if all six of your resources are on the same host, they could simply be blocking. Furthermore, if these resources are JavaScript or some other resources that *may* be parsed on load.

Also note that the total time is when the page load event fires, so this doesn't necessarily mean that is a *white screen* for six seconds.

Check out the [YSlow guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/#introduction) for more details tips on performance. I also recommend *[Building Faster Websites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309)* if you're really interested in this subject.

Comment: @roman m : I concur with @Jason McCreary . Even though the individual files took around 3 seconds in total to download (if u add up each individual time) ... there's still some time to process each file. Look at the huge gap between the 2nd and 3rd file. that *white-section* is still time to process .. not to download. In summary: 3 secs to download, 6 secs to process. (and those 3 secs doesn't take into consideration, parallel downloading).